# How to verify email receiving?

Tags: android, email

As we are doing some automation testing for android email client, and I am thinking about the receiving verification.
One plan I can give is the screenshot comparison, but it is a bit complex to setup test.
any other method to get the information of email receiving?
any API or flag for new email in android?